# componentWillReceiveProps not triggering function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have React Redux app with two separate components (Login & MessageBar) that are listening to two difference pieces of state each (login & messages).

When the logins fails an action is dispatched with an error message, the MessageBar component maps the state to props and triggers a function that displays the message. This is done through on componentWillReceiveProps.

When the same action is dispatched again the same message is sent, however componentWillReceiveProps does not trigger the function anymore.

I think this is because that piece of state has not changed. I like the idea of calling an action to display message from my actions vs a component. Any ideas as to how I can achieve the function trigger with the same state? Or is there alternative way?

```
//** COMPONENTS **////
 class Login extends Component {
 /* ...calls action with username/password */
 }

 class MessageBar extends Component {
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { type, message } = nextProps;
    if (type && message) {
      this.dropdown.alertWithType(type, '', message);
    }
   }
   render() {
     <DropdownAlert
       ref={ref => this.dropdown = ref}
       errorColor={Colors.red}
       successColor={Colors.green}
       defaultContainer={{
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 24 : 0,
        padding: 8
       }}
      zIndex={100}
    />
  }
 }
 const mapStateToProps = ({ messages }) => ({ ..messages });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MessageBar)

//** ACTION **/
export const LoginUser = ({ email, password}) => {
  if (!email || ! password ) {
    dispatch({ 
     type: 'global_message',
     payload: { 
       type: 'error',
       message: 'Invalid email/password'
     });
  } else {
    /** Some api call with dispatch... **/
  }
}


//** REDUCER **/
   export default (state = {}, { type, payload }) => {

    switch (type) {
        case 'global_message':
          return { ...payload }

        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Here's the solution I got working. componentWillReceiveProps now triggers my function and the state is returned in an object inside the first key of the array.

```
/** REDUCER **/
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'global_message':
      return [{
        ...payload, message: 'Incorrect email/password'
      }];
};

/** COMPONENT **/
class MessageBar extends Component {
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { type, message } = nextProps[0];
    if (type && message) {
      this.dropdown.alertWithType(type, '', message);
    }
   }
   render() {
     <DropdownAlert
       ref={ref => this.dropdown = ref}
       errorColor={Colors.red}
       successColor={Colors.green}
       defaultContainer={{
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 24 : 0,
        padding: 8
       }}
      zIndex={100}
    />
  }
 }
 const mapStateToProps = ({ messages }) => ({ ..messages });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MessageBar)
```

Comment: try consoling type && message in componentWillReceiveProps. What you are getting

Comment: I tried that, it's not triggering. I placed a console.log in the mapStateToProps which does trigger but not componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: Are the action types different as shown in your post?

Comment: They are both the same, sorry typo (fixed). It's "global_message"

Comment: Is it always hitting constructor then?

Comment: Only the initial store state passed to MessageBar his the constructor().  

The componentWillReceiveProps() does trigger when the reducer returns a state using 
`return [...state, { ...payload }] `, 
however Redux docs does mention the spread operator is also valid
`return { ...state ...payload}`

Comment: Here's the solutions I got working. 

At my reducer

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'global_message':
      return [{
        ...payload, message: 'Incorrect email/password'
      }];
}